# How to automatically enter a table value into another calculation sheet, and get the returning outcome value back to the table?

Tags: excel-2010

Not sure if I formulated that in an understandable way. Basically, I have sheet1 with a table filled with characters with their theoretical DPS where they just attack forever. For a more realistic DPS, sheet2 calculates their DPS and TDO based on how long they survive the enemy. Sheet2 can at the moment manually calculate that if I enter the character name myself. However, I'd like the 'real' DPS values to be automatically added to the table in the sheet1. That would, however, require somehow putting the character name in sheet2's input value, and then copying the output to the table in sheet1. Is there a way to do this? (Because how long they survive varies, several index matches are used to get the damage at the moment of death. That's why I needed a separate sheet and can't do it in the same table).

I have no idea what what I want, if it exists, is called, so I can't exactly search for it.